# At which point in UpdateView is the data saved?

Tags: python, django, orm

I was wondering when the data given to an `UpdateView` was saved.

I have the following situation: I update a model object via a form. I would expect the changes to the model only to be saved after the `UpdateView`'s `form_valid` is through. But when I print the object attributes right at the start of `form_valid`, they have already changed to the new ones inserted into the form.

So when exactly is the change to the model saved and how would I go about if I wanted to do something with the previous values?

I am relatively new to Django and I hope that this question is not too far off track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects received in `form_valid` are those of the yet unsaved object, not of the object retrieved from the database.

Try

```
newobject = Mymodel.objects.get(pk=object.pk)
```

To verify that the object retrieved this way from the database still has the old attributes.

*Note: This will not work on `CreateView` because objects in `CreateView` don't exist in the database yet and therefore do not have a PK yet.*

The actual work of saving the updated object is done in `ModelFormMixin` line 123, one of the Mixin Classes of `UpdateView`. From the [Source Code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 4):

The object is not saved to the database until `form.save()` is called in [`form_valid()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#form_valid) method. If you override the method and save with `instance = form.save(commit=False)`, it is not saved to the database until you call `instance.save()`.

However, when `form.is_valid()` is called in the [`post()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#post) method, this immediately updates `self.object` with the new values. Therefore, if you access self.object in the `form_valid()` method, it already has the new values.

You could refetch the original object from the database:

```
original_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.object.pk)
```

If you just want to know which fields changed, `form.changed_data` might be enough for you.

Comment: If you were curious about where the instance actually gets updated, it happens (as of Django 3.1.4) in the line `self.instance = construct_instance(...)` called in `django.forms.models.BaseModelForm._post_clean`. `construct_instance()` "constructs and returns a model instance from the bound form's cleaned_data".

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of `UpdateView.form_valid` is as follows (straight from Django):

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, save the associated model.
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

If you wanted to access the "old" instance within `form_valid` you could do the following:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    updated_instance = form.save(commit=False)
    original_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=updated.pk)

    # Do what ever you want with these two instances.
    # ...

    # The form is saved in the super call below, hence the 
    # commit=False above.
    return super(self, MyView).form_valid(form)
```